# WPF DataGrid - one itemssource, multiple views, multiple filters

Tags: wpf, datagrid, filter

I have an ObservableCollection that I would like to bind to multiple datagrids, each one displayed in its own window, and each datagrid having a different filter. I was initially using this:

```
ICollectionView m_icvs = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ListOrder)
m_icvs.Filter = OrderFilter;
```

And it worked fine for one filter, but when I needed to open more windows, each with its own filter, the filter would change across all windows. I think this is because all of the windows are using the same ICollectionView, which is returned by the GetDefaultView. So I found another post with a similar problem - [Multiple Views of Observable Collection with Datagrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786278/multiple-views-of-observable-collection-with-datagrid). I tried to adapt this solution to my problem but could not get it to work. This is what I tried:

```
private CollectionViewSource m_cvs;
public CollectionViewSource Cvs
{
    get { return m_cvs; }
    set { m_cvs = value; }
}

ObservableCollection<OrderItem> m_listOrder;
public ObservableCollection<OrderItem> ListOrder
{
    get { return m_listOrder; }
    set { m_listOrder = value; }
}

public OrderDlg(ObservableCollection<OrderItem> listOrder)
{
    ListOrder = listOrder;
    ...
    Cvs = new CollectionViewSource();
    Cvs.Source = ListOrder;
    Cvs.View.Filter = delegate(object o) { return OrderFilter(o); };
}
```

xaml:

```
<DataGrid
ItemsSource="{Binding Cvs}">
...
</DataGrid>
```

Using this approach, the DataGrid doesn't display data, even if I comment out the line that applies the filter.

Comment: What issue you facing in second approach?

Comment: just nothing shows up in the datagrid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> DataGrid's itemsource should be binded to **ICollectionView** and **not
>   CollectionViewSource**.

Create a property which will return `ICollectionView` from your `CollectionViewSource` object -

```
public ICollectionView CV
{
   get
   {
      return m_cvs.View;
   }
}
```

Update your binding in XAML -

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding CV}"/>
```